# Updating to latest version of CocoaPods?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm having some issues installing `Alamofire 4.0` into my project.

I've got the latest version of **Xcode**, running **Swift 3**, and when I try to install alamofire I'm getting like 800 compiler errors.

Apparently

> CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+

> [!] `some_cocoapod` requires CocoaPods version `>= X.Y.Z`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `Z.Y.X`.

I looked at the version of CocoaPods I have in terminal and it says I'm at 1.0.1.

Running an update didn't work I guess because [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) 1.1 is in beta.

So I'm not exactly sure how to update it up to where I'm good to go.
Unless being out of date doesn't force like 800 compiler errors? Does that sound like some other issue?

Answer (score 1068, accepted):

Execute the following on your terminal to get the **latest stable version**:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Add `--pre` to get the latest pre release:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

If you originally installed the cocoapods gem using `sudo`, you should use that command again.

Later on, when you're actively using CocoaPods by installing pods, you will be notified when new versions become available with a CocoaPods X.X.X is now available, please update message.

Comment: Drop the `--pre` if you want the latest stable version

Comment: Is it equivalent when I use `--pre` or `gem install cocoapods -v 1.4.0.rc.1` for now? Will it be the same?

Comment: Does  `rc` mean **non stable version**?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Release candidate, so usually means not officially stable

Comment: Does not seem to work without a *pod setup* afterwards.

Comment: If you get an error during install for the bin folder you can add the -n /usr/local/bin before the cocoapods after the install on that line.  This will get your to the latest version and get by the read only permissions of the default folder.

Comment: Never install dependencies with `sudo`!

Comment: ATTENTION: This approach does not work for newer MacOS versions where System Integrity Protection is on by default. Check below for a better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103633/2328732

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying the ruby installation that comes pre installed on a Mac. Instead you could install rbenv and use a separate ruby installation where sudo is not required.

Comment: Non-`sudo` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77171209/4995828

Answer (score 221):

### **If you are using Homebrew**

Open terminal and type:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

If that does not work, try:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

After that, run:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Comment: is it possible that the homebrew version is sometimes behind the gem version?

Comment: It is possible, im getting 1.9.1 while the latest on gem is 1.9.3

Comment: I am also getting the message "cocoapods 1.9.1 already installed" though the version seems to be 1.9.3 @BananZ did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Nope, as the change is minimal, i just ignore the warning -> 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases' and 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/compare/1.9.1...1.9.3'. 
Anyways I have just checked, latest 1.9.3 is available in homebrew now..'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/55646'. If you are interested you may try to contribute to Brew for future upgrades (I have never done it but will try soon in near future).

Comment: My issue was in linking part 
`brew link --overwrite cocoapods`
now problem solved thanks

Comment: Make sure pod --version has the same version as the expected Cocoapods installation

Answer (score 171):

Open the `Terminal` `->` `copy` below command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It will install the latest stable version of `cocoapods`.

**after that, you need to update pod using below command**

```
pod setup
```

**You can check pod version using below command**

```
pod --version
```

Comment: Do you need to run <code>pod setup --verbose</code>  after this as well?

Comment: @GraSim Yes. It is required

Comment: Your gemfile might be locked to an older version, in which case run `bundle update cocoapods` to get your project using the most recent cocoapods

Answer (score 123):

If you got **System Integrity Protection** enabled or any other permission write error, which is enabled by default since macOS Sierra release, you should update CocoaPods, running this line in terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n/usr/local/bin
```

After installing, check your pod version:

```
pod --version
```

You will get rid of this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory
```

And it will install latest CocoaPods:

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-x.x.x
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-x.x.x
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-x.x.x
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me to upgrade from 1.8.4 to 1.9.1. Not sure if I may have installed using brew previously.

Comment: this should be the top answer

Comment: agree this can be top answer. This answer helped me to update from `1.9.1` to `1.10.0.rc.1`

Answer (score 43):

For those with a [sudo-less CocoaPods installation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation) (i.e., you do *not* want to grant RubyGems admin privileges), you don't need the `sudo` command to update your CocoaPods installation at all:

```sh
gem install cocoapods
```

You can find out *where* the CocoaPods gem is installed with:

```sh
gem which cocoapods
```

If this is *within* your home directory, you should definitely run `gem install cocoapods` without using `sudo`.

Finally, to check which CocoaPods you are currently running type:

```sh
pod --version
```

Answer (score 26):

I had to do this, was stuck on 1.9.1 on macOS

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: this one “actually” helped!
Thanks. :) +1

Comment: Regardless of what I tried, including a few other suggestions here, this is the only one that worked for me. In my specific case I was on Big Sur 11.6 and stuck on Cocoapods 10.1.

Answer (score 20):

Non of the above solved my problem, you can check pod version using two commands:

1. `pod --version`
2. `gem which cocoapods`

In my case `pod --version` always showed "1.5.0" while `gem which cocopods` shows
`Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.0/lib/cocoapods.rb`. I tried every thing but unable to update version showed from `pod --version`. `sudo gem install cocopods` result in installing latest version but `pod --version` always showing previous version. Finally I tried these commands:

1. `sudo gem update`
2. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
4. ``` pod setup``pod install ```

The catch for me was sudo gem update. Hopefully it will help any body else.

Comment: This answer helped me, but don't use `sudo` if you have RVM.

Comment: This helped in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Below are steps to update cocoapods :

1. Open **terminal** (Shortcut : `Press cmd + space tab` to open Spotlight then text in `terminal`)
2. Use command **sudo gem install cocoapod**s. This will ask for system password due to security concern thereafter it installs gems

[image: Screenshot 1]

3. Now, set up pod using `pod setup` command. This will setup cocoapods master repo.

[image: Screenshot 2]

4. You can check the version of cocoapods using `pod --version` command.

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 13):

You can solve this problem by these Commands:

**First:**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**Desp:** type user mac password now your cocoapods will be replace with a stable version.

You can find out where the CocoaPods gem is installed with:

```
gem which cocoapods
```

if you have cloned the repo then type this command:

```
pod repo update
```

close your xcode and run this command

```
Pod install
```

Answer (score 10):

If this

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

gives you this error:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Try this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Comment: The second one helped

Answer (score 9):

**This is a really quick & detailed solution**

Open the Terminal and execute the following to get the latest stable version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Add --pre to get the latest pre release:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

**Incase any error occured**

Try uninstall and install again:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Run after updating CocoaPods

```
sudo gem clean cocoapods
```

After updating CocoaPods, also need to update Podfile.lock file in your project.

Go to your project directory

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 8):

Very Smoot and Easy Solution

```
//MARK: -Latest stable version:
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre 

//MARK: -If not work then
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre -n /usr/local/bin

//MARK: - if upper command not works you can use below mention command as well!
brew install cocoapods

brew upgrade cocoapods

brew link cocoapods
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried updating and it didn't work. Finally , I had to completely remove (manually )cocoapods, cocoapods-core , cocoapods-try.. and any other package used by cocoapods. Use this terminal command to list all the packages:

`gem list --local | grep cocoapods`

After that , I also deleted **./cocoapods** folder from the user's root folder.

Answer (score 6):

After trying all the steps above, with nothing working, I ran `bundle update` which seems to have done the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Refer this link https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

```
brew install cocoapods

brew upgrade cocoapods

brew link cocoapods
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem in myproject when `pod version` and `gem which cocoapods` always return difference version.

All I had to do is remove Gemfile.lock in my project and bundle install again. It removed the locked cocoapods version and install a newer one.

Hope that helps some one here.

Comment: Thanks , this works for cocoapods-1.11.2

Answer (score 3):

**Using Bundler?**

Run `bundle update cocoapods`

Answer (score 2):

If you updated `sudo gem install cocoapods` but it's still showing the old version you just need to type `bundle update` in your terminal to update the bundle and `pod --version` will show the newest version you installed

Answer (score 1):

For me helped these steps

- gem uninstall cocoapods (select old version of cocoapods)
- bundle install
- gem install cocoapods
- pod install

Answer (score 0):

On my M1 Mac, I had a separate version of Homebrew installed for the Silicon/Arm64 side.

`brew upgrade cocoapods` was defaulting to a rosetta install of homebrew. I kept running it, and couldn't figure out why cocoapods was not updating. So I had to run it in a way that targets the M1 side of things instead of Rosetta.

I had previously aliased the Arm `brew` to `mbrew`. So I had to run `mbrew upgrade cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to not use `sudo`, we can actually install CocoaPods on a per user basis as follows:

`gem install --user cocoapods`

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions might be (at least it worked for me and seems to be least intrusive change) this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725230

tl;dr;
find and change `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` to `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Answer (score 0):

My issue solved with

```
brew update
brew install cocoapods
pod repo update
pod --version
```

> run these command in order to install cocoapods

Answer (score -1):

write on your terminal this:
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre

for update the gem of cocoapods to lastest version

Answer (score -3):

First check cocoapods versionlike

```
pod --version
```

then update like

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

after update you can also check cocoapods version.

[image]

Answer (score -7):

I change the line "pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'" to "pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire', :commit => '3cc5b4e'" after that in terminal: "pod install --repo-update" and it works.