# Error when adding OneSignal Plugin to Flutter Project

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal, podfile

I'm trying to add OneSignal to my flutter project and I followed this tutorial

https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

but when I run

```
pod install
```

it shows error message like below

```
!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `s' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007f86880b7fa0>.

# from /Users/macmini1/Projects/flutter/my_project/ios/Podfile:58
# -------------------------------------------
# target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
> s.dependency 'OneSignalDynamic', '>= 2.8.8', '< 3.0'
# end
# -------------------------------------------
```

Anybody helps?

Comment: BTW That documentation doesn't appear to be up to date, the latest version is onesignal: ^1.0.2

Comment: yeah it very disappointing that OneSignal not updating its documentation for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you first off all update your pod using terminal from this url
[Updating to latest version of CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods/41518456),
i am adding same pod "OneSignal" in my project and it's perfectly adding done.

Comment: I already installed the latest CocoaPods (1.5.3) but the error still there, what version of OneSignal that you installed?

Comment: @esthrim i have installed "OneSignal 2.9.0".

Comment: the latest version for now is 1.1.0 from here https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal 
what package are you pointing at @Mayank Palotra

Comment: @MohamedSelim According to https://cocoapods.org/ (https://cocoapods.org/pods/OneSignal) the latest version is 2.10.0.

Comment: Aha, I thought he was speaking about the version of the OneSignal flutter plugin,
Thanks @Mayank