# Cocoapods behaving awkwardly

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

*I use Macos Mojave; version 10.14.6
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) AND Xcode Version 11.3 (11C29)*

I am doing some development in **XCode** and this issue has been repeating in the project I am currently working on.

One of the pods I am using in the project is ***CryptoSwift.***

When I run `pod update` , I get the error at the end:

***[!] `CryptoSwift` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.9.1`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.7.5`.***

It also says:

*CocoaPods 1.10.0 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`*

I check my cocoapods version using:

```
pod --version
```

This gives me:

**1.7.5**

But when I use:

`gem which cocoapods` , I get:

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods.rb`

I have severally tried:

`sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` AND `sudo gem install cocoapods`

to get the latest version of cocoapods

**QUESTION:**

How do I install cocoapods version **1.10.0** so that ***pod update*** stops complaining that I am on version **1.7.5**

**NOTE**

When I run: `gem list cocoapods`

It gives,

```
cocoapods (1.10.0)
cocoapods-core (1.10.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.4)
cocoapods-downloader (1.4.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.5.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating to latest version of CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods)

Comment: @zeytin , this does not answer my question. Another answer on the link you shared is what answered my question. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65258398/1845404

Comment: @gbenroscience this is already an answer in the same question the link i shared, anyway good luck

Comment: @zeytin , that is exactly what I said