# Issues while building iOS project with flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

After upgrading Xcode 15 beta 5, cannot build project.

Error being displayed

> Firebase 1 issue
> DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

> FirebaseAnalytics 1 issue
> DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

Tried to deintegrate, reinstall and updating pods, issues doesn't resolves.

Flutter V. 3.10.6

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest version of Cocoapods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It seem issue of old Cocoapods version with Xcode 15. This issue is resolved in the CocoaPods version [1.13.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.13.0),

With Cocoapods old version, you can fix this issue by edit Podfile like following

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the code help! After cocoapods update their public release later, how do we remove the special things this piece of code does to keep the default expected normal behavior?

Comment: @fphelp when update just delete Podfile.lock file and Pods/ folder. And run pod install again.

Comment: See also [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012#issuecomment-1709418017) if you get: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Comment: It's embarassing that Apple continues to release bugged version of their major development IDE and related software...every new version of XCode carries issues! EM BA RAS SING! I'm disgusted!

Comment: Don't forget, after the pod file is updated you need to run pod install again in the iOS directory!

Comment: I'm getting this when trying to run a Flutter app: Error (Xcode): 123 duplicate symbols Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Answer (score 61):

## Xcode 15 Oct 2023 Solution

The below solution should handle all of the following

1. [`'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012#issuecomment-1709418017) (for me this was related to flavors)
2. [`Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012#issuecomment-1726439202) (for me this came from a live activity and widget extension)

#### Step 1: Update Podfile (Flutter / Xcode 15)

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
          File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
  end
end
```

#### Step 2: Update Build Phases (Extension)

1. Open Xcode
2. Click "Runner" in project navigator (top left)
3. Click Targets -> Runner in sidebar
4. Click Build Phases (top bar)
5. Move "Embed App Extension" (or "Embed Foundation Extension" or similar) above the Run Script step (which includes code about framework)

If this doesn't work, check https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974 for more ideas.

#### Clean Everything

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && rm podfile.lock && arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

---

NOTE: This issue is resolved in the latest [cocaopod version](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.13.0).

Comment: Causes Thread 1: signal SIGABRT for me

Comment: @bjmcallister try deleting derived data, pod deintegrate and pod install. This must work

Answer (score 19):

Until the fix has been published, just open a Terminal window and run this command from your project folder:

```
find . -name "*.xcconfig" -type f -exec grep -l 'DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR' {} \; \
| while IFS= read -r file; do sed -i '' 's/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/TOOLCHAIN_DIR/g' "$file"; done
```

After that the error is gone and won't return unless you run `pod update` or `pod install` again, in which case you must run that command again.

Comment: I think this is a more appropriate solution or workaround, as this problem is specific to Xcode 15 and Cocoapods, as it's affecting all the iOS projects, regardless of the technology used (Flutter, native, etc).

This was already reported here
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012

It's a matter of wait until the official fix, so no need to update the pods file

Comment: This corrected the issue for all of our Realm and Firebase projects. Very much appreciated as we were dead in the water.

Comment: This worked for me too. I was having issues with adding Firebase to my iOS Xcode project. Thanks

Comment: after trying different solution this one works.

Answer (score 8):

**I have solved those issues in this way:**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

if you use [inAppWebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) for flutter then come error like this :

Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'WebKit'

So you can add in Your pubspec.yaml file Like this:

```
flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Estrelio/flutter_inappwebview.git
      ref: fix-xcode-17
```

Answer (score 5):

## Update Xcode to Version 15 Solution

If you faced this issue after updating the Xcode to version 15 and can't run your flutter app on iOS platform.

You need to update the CocoaPods to the latest stable version by this command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If you are using Homebrew, write this command instead in terminal:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

or

```
brew install cocoapods
```

**REMEMBER**

1. Clean your flutter project by run this command in project terminal:

   flutter clean
2. Remove Pods directory inside iOS directory
3. Build your app on iOS platform and Congrats.

Answer (score 3):

I solved modifying the pod_install in this way:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
```

end

I kept this line of code:

```
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
```

because without it I have found other problems like:

```
    Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Flutter'
/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_progress_hud_nsn-0.4.0/ios/Classes/ModalProgressHudNsnPlugin.swift:0:7


Encountered error while building for device.
```

Answer (score 2):

> [1.13.0 shipped with the fix.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065#issuecomment-1732182840)

Update Cocoapods to v1.13:

```bash
sudo arch -x86_64 gem update cocoapods
```

Then in your flutter project, run:

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update && cd ..
cd macos && arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update && cd ..
```

Answer (score 1):

for me i had to combine a couple of solutions - one of which being upping the minimum deployment target to 13. final running pod_install looks like this

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: After trying many more solutions, this works for me. But I got a new problem after using this. 

So I need to solved that problem too.

Answer (score 1):

**After searching for many more solutions, I finally solved the issue.**

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Yes, not only changing, but this solves my problem.**

**After changing my `podfile` to this, I got a new problem, and that is:**

```
Error (Xcode): type argument 'nw_proxy_config_t' (aka 'struct nw_proxy_config *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsi
teDataStore.h:119:46


Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'WebKit'
/Users/rokomari/rokomari-ios-flutter/rokomari_ios/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.framework/Headers/flutter_inappwebview-Swift.h:893:
8
```

So I need to solve this problem too.

To solve this problem, you have to change some files in your iOS directory:

**Step 1:** Go to this directory `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h`

**Step 2:** Open this file named `WKWebsiteDataStore.h` and in line 113, change the code to:

Change from:

```
|| ((TARGET_OS_IOS || TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 170000) \
```

to:

```
|| ((TARGET_OS_IOS || TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 180000) \
```

**This is how I solved my problem !!**

**Note: `WKWebsiteDataStore.h` file is not editable on `XCode`. So you have to open this file on Default `TextEditor`, then change this code above I and replace the file with a new one. I hope this will solve your issue.**

**If you are struggling to edit:**

1. Open Terminal
2. Run:

open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/

**If you use XCode beta, replace the line `Xcode.app` with `Xcode-beta.app` .**

3. Then find `WKWebsiteDataStore.h` in the finder and right-click open with TextEdit. Edit the file and save it again.

Answer (score 0):

if you use flutter, change pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
          File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
          end
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this in your podfile, fixed it for me

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of codes, This worked for me, just add a combination of the above code on the podfile if the above solutions didn't work for you.

```
        post_integrate do |installer|
      compiler_flags_key = 'COMPILER_FLAGS'
      project_path = 'Pods/Pods.xcodeproj'
    
      project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
      project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if build_phase.is_a?(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXSourcesBuildPhase)
            build_phase.files.each do |file|
              if !file.settings.nil? && file.settings.key?(compiler_flags_key)
                compiler_flags = file.settings[compiler_flags_key]
                file.settings[compiler_flags_key] = compiler_flags.gsub(/-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0\s*/, '')
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
      project.save()
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
        end
      end
    end
```

```
Flutter 3.13.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e1e47221e8 (6 weeks ago) • 2023-08-22 21:43:18 -0700
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
Cocopods 1.13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this

```
cd ios
```

after

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

after

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Then look for the **iproxy** and open it manually with the termianl so that flutter can open it when running in development mode, you find it in the path

```
users/{mi_user}/{folder_contains_flutter}/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/usbmuxd
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cocoapods version is above 13.0.0.

If it doesn't work even if you upgraded to latest version, delete the Podfile.lock and build again.