# DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Trying to run a flutter app after latest Xcode and iOS 17 update and get the following error "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead"

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
            # You can enable the permissions needed here. For example to enable camera
            # permission, just remove the `#` character in front so it looks like this:
            #
            # ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
            # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
            #
            #  Preprocessor definitions can be found in: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler_apple/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
            config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
              '$(inherited)',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
              # 'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
              # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
              # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
              'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
              # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
              # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
              # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
        
              ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
              # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
                
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
              # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
              # 'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
              # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',   
                
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
              # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
              # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
        
              ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
              # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
            ]
         end
    end
end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Anyone know how I can modify this to work?
This seems to happen that there's some sort of error after upgrading Xcode.

Comment: this worked for me:  ```sudo gem install specific_install
sudo gem specific_install https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods.git```

Comment: I would recommend this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77134628/1746142

Comment: This should fix it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77138033/1759443

Answer (score 78):

Upgrade Cocoapods v1.13.0.

Brew command:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Without Brew:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then run in your project/ios folder

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: You will likely need to run  pod install after updating Cocoapods

Comment: Thank you @user3847320.  After the install I had to `cd ios` and then `pod install`

Answer (score 26):

In Xcode 15 Apple changed the variable which points to the default toolchain location to `$TOOLCHAIN_DIR` from `$DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR.` If some project/target used `$DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` then it need to be replace by `$TOOLCHAIN_DIR.`

**1. Fix for CocoaPods:**

you can add the following script in your Podfile to automatically update `$DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` to `$TOOLCHAIN_DIR`.

```
 post_install do |installer|
    xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # For xcode 15+ only
             if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**2. Fix for your project:**

If you see some references of `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` in your main project/taget, then you need to update that manually.

**------------- OR -------------**

**Upgarade Cocoapods v1.13.0**

brew command

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

without brew

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I searched for `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` in my Flutter project and replaced it with `TOOLCHAIN_DIR` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have cocoapods 1.14.3.1 installed and the problem still persists. But the cocoapods-file approach worked. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 10):

for my swift project, the error was showing in firebase and firebase analytics, so I just replaced

DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with TOOLCHAIN_DIR in Firebase.release and .debug
and same in FirebaseAnalytics.release and debug

Comment: Additional information : Go to Pods > Firebase > Support Files and Firebase.release and .debug

Answer (score 2):

That issue was fixed on cocoapods-1.13.0.

So i installed 1.13.0 and after that updated the pod and issue was gone. I think this is the easiest way to resolve it.

```
gem install cocoapods // if its doesn't work just because some permission problem, can use "sudo install cocoapods". But remember, always be aware when use 'sudo'. Its not recommended. 
pod update
```

I tried to add that code on below to the Podfile but didn't work on my case. Maybe i couldn't make it idk.

```
post_install do |installer|
xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # For xcode 15+ only
         if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
            xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
            xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
            xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
            File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For my flutter project These commands run by me

1. install ruby
   `brew install ruby`
2. install and upgrade cocoapods
   `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. clean flutter project
   `flutter clean`
4. flutter run from terminal
   `flutter run`
5. then i searched "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR" in entire project via android studio and replaced with "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"
6. finally `flutter run` command
7. project should be run now!

---

Sometimes we need to manually install pod files in ios folder for that below commands is helpful

1. `cd ios`
2. `rm Podfile.lock`
3. `rm -rf Pods`
4. `pod cache clean --all`
5. `pod deintegrate`
6. `pod setup`
7. `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [Cocoapods v1.13.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.13.0) is out now, which should resolve this issue.

Original answer:

We are waiting for the cocoapod maintainers to make a new release with [this fix](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/12009) included. [See edit above]

Until then you can try another alternative fix from [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/12009#issuecomment-1726946681) or [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/12009#issuecomment-1715953759) or point the cocoapods gem in your `Gemfile` to the cocoapods git repo and it's master branch.

Comment: well I am on 1.13.0 and its not working... sadness

Answer (score 1):

Replacing this code in podfile worked for me.
After adding that, you have to delete the existing pods folder and then generate pods again.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
    xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
    xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
    File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal execute

```
pod --version
```

And check you have at least v1.13

Otherwise, execute

```
gem update cocoapods
```

then, in your repo folder

```
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Flutter** developers use this in **ios/Podfile**:

```dart
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
    xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
    xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
    File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your podfile
And run the pod install

```
# post install
  post_install do |installer|
 xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print 
  $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    
    # For ML Kit
    config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 
   "arm64"
    config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15'

      # For xcode 15+ only
       if config.base_configuration_reference && 
  Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, 
         "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
          File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
       end
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**First :**

- pod install
- pod repo update
- pod update

**Then Update Pod File**

```
post_install do |installer|

  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
    xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
    IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using this command on a console:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR' {} \; \
| while IFS= read -r file; do sed -i '' 
's/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/TOOLCHAIN_DIR/g' "$file"; done
```

Comment: Could you explain what it does. It's never a good practice to copy/paste command lines into a terminal without understanding what it does.