# After installing new version of XCode 15.0 unable to run app XCode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode15

I have installed new version of Xcode 15.0. After this I am unable to run my flutter app. It is showing me following error:

```
Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead
```

Comment: This should have the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77138033/1759443

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter or React Native Xcode 15 Error (Xcode): DT\_TOOLCHAIN\_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY\_SEARCH\_PATHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136958/flutter-or-react-native-xcode-15-error-xcode-dt-toolchain-dir-cannot-be-used)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved those issues in this way:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a good practice to include explanations in your solution to help others understand what's happening under the hood.

Here's a solution that includes a effective explanation of what was causing the issue and how the provided solution successfully resolved it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77250992/6666942

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution from [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012).

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
          File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
          end
      end
  end
```

Feel free to explore more answers from others. The above-written code has the highest reactions among all others.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 15, Apple made a modification to the variable that points to the default toolchain location, replacing $DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with $TOOLCHAIN_DIR. If your project or target relies on the previous variable, you should update it to use $TOOLCHAIN_DIR.

To perform this replacement, you can add the following code snippet at the end of your project's Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

After making this change in your Podfile, you will need to install the pods again via the terminal using the command:

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the same problem and to fix this
you have to
rename this DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR to TOOLCHAIN_DIR
in the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS find it and fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue
what work for me was just changing the version of
flutter_inappwebview:    to the latest version  ^5.8.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on macOS 13.6.5 22G621 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
>     • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at /Users/user/Documents/Flutter Sdk/flutter
>     • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>     • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (3 months ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
>     • Engine revision 3f3e560236
>     • Dart version 3.2.3
>     • DevTools version 2.28.4
>
>     > [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>     > version 34.0.0)
>     >     • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
>     >     • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
>     >     • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
>     >     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
>     >     • All Android licenses accepted.
> ```

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '13.0'
    
    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
    
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
    
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              # You can remove unused permissions here
              # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
              # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
              config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
                '$(inherited)',
    
    
          
    
              ]
    
            end
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
      end
    end
    post_integrate do |installer|
      compiler_flags_key = 'COMPILER_FLAGS'
      project_path = 'Pods/Pods.xcodeproj'
    
      project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)
      project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_phases.each do |build_phase|
          if build_phase.is_a?(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXSourcesBuildPhase)
            build_phase.files.each do |file|
              if !file.settings.nil? && file.settings.key?(compiler_flags_key)
                compiler_flags = file.settings[compiler_flags_key]
                file.settings[compiler_flags_key] = compiler_flags.gsub(/-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0\s*/, '')
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
      project.save()
    end
```