# Flutter or React Native Xcode 15 Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS

Tags: flutter

upon upgrading my Xcode today to version 15, I receive the following error when building my app for IOS:

```
Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead
```

It appears some specific dependencies are causing this issue, in my case:

- objectbox_flutter_libs: ^2.2.1
- firebase_core: ^2.16.0

I have no idea how to solve this issue, and I'll really appreciate any advice!

Thanks!

Comment: This should be the fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77138033/1759443

Comment: Try to upgrade the latest version of Cocoapods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: Xcode 15 has been officially released, and I think it's time to release CocoaPods 13.0, and 1.13.0 shipped with the fix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues while building iOS project with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76791937/issues-while-building-ios-project-with-flutter)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

***UPDATE: This issue is resolved in the latest [cocaopod version](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.13.0).***

> Command to upgrade: brew upgrade cocoapods

***so if you install that you shouldn't need the solutions below:***

**Solution 1:**
Add this code to your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

After that run a pod update (make sure that the iOS folder is the current directory before running pod update).

> pod update

**Solution 2:** [Issues while building iOS project with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76791937/issues-while-building-ios-project-with-flutter)

Check out this for multi flavour config.

**Solution 3:**
**if you use [inAppWebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) for flutter then come error like this :**

Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'WebKit'

So you can add in Your pubspec.yaml file Like this:

```
flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/Estrelio/flutter_inappwebview.git
      ref: fix-xcode-17
```

**Solution 4 (For non-flutter users):**

Remove the below line from the script.

> flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

Comment: I tried this solution by @Kyle Venn and it indeed works. However, it's important to note that this should only be used as a temporary solution until the next cocopods update comes out.

Comment: This fails with: undefined method `real_path' for nil:NilClass. I have multiple flavours in my app, and this doesn't help with the issue.

Comment: I updated, check once again.

Comment: I tried that solution but then I'm getting this when trying to run the app:

Error (Xcode): 123 duplicate symbols
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I have tried this and other solutions, but once this error is fixed I end up with this error: B/BL out of range 135915360 (max +/-128MB) to ''

Comment: @LukaszC. I asked the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139621/xcode-15-undefined-symbols-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-s. If that doesn't work, simply delete & recreate your ios folder using 'flutter create --platforms ios .' (MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP!)

Comment: @PreemPalver2 No, I cant "simply" delete the iOS folder. I have five big apps to support, and each has a complex and custom Xcode configuration. It would take me a week to recreate this. I often see this "simply delete" suggestion because people assume there is nothing in the ios folder, which often isn't the case for bigger apps. I'll have a look if setting an old linker helps.

Comment: Setting the linker combined with the other solution have worked. ;)

Comment: btw, comment "flutter" line if you don't have flutter

Comment: @pw2, added your suggestion to answer.

Answer (score 27):

> [1.13.0 shipped with the fix.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065#issuecomment-1732182840)

Update Cocoapods to v1.13:

```bash
gem update cocoapods
```

Then in your ios project dir, run:

```bash
pod update
```

Comment: Even with version 1.13.0 I get these errors:

Could not build module 'WebKit'


/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h:120:47 type argument 'nw_proxy_config_t' (aka 'struct nw_proxy_config *') is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type

Answer (score 8):

**For Flutter Devs and HomeBrew Users**

A fix for this was released from the Cocoapods team

> [Github issue discussion here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065#issuecomment-1732182840)

**Upgrade your Cocoapods to v1.13.0:**

Run this command in your mac terminal

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Check cocoapods version ensure v1.13.0

```
pod --version
```

**Delete the Pods directory and Podfile.lock in your iOS module's root folder.**

```
cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf Podfile. lock
```

**Install pods**

Run the below from the root of your iOS module

```
pod install
```

This should fix the error.

Comment: yep this worked for me! But I'm still running into another problem saying – Could not build module 'WebKit'

Answer (score 6):

Solution that worked for me: Xcode 15 with Flutter

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Build error with this change: 
'undefined method xcconfigs' for #<Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXNativeTarget:0x000000014aa715c0>

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
find . -name "*.xcconfig" -type f -exec grep -l 'DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR' {} \; \
| while IFS= read -r file; do sed -i '' 's/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/TOOLCHAIN_DIR/g' "$file"; done
```

in my case I ran it in my project folder.

source: **https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/xcode-15-cocoapods/245603**

Answer (score 4):

Try this, its works in react-native:

```
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the error. Just add the below code into Pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
  xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # For xcode 15+ only
            if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
            end
        end
  end
end
```

**Note:** Delete the Pod folder first, then go to the **`ios`** directory and try to run **`pod install`** after refactoring the pod file using the above code provided.

Answer (score 3):

With Flutter version 3.13.5 the issues with Xcode 15 seems to be fixed. What I did was upgrade Flutter, remove macOS folder (I believe same holds for iOS) and recreate platform project:

```
flutter upgrade
rm -r macOS
flutter clean
flutter create .
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

open /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h, change __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED to 180000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

## If you're using Flutter, Firebase, XCode 15...

I struggled with this problem for a long time. This is what fixed it for me.

1. In XCode, navigate to your `Podfile` and on the chunk of code (should be at the bottom of the file) that starts with `post_install ...` you want to change/replace it to this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

2. Add your Firebase `GoogleService-Info` file  to XCode. This must be done through XCode — not the file system — else it won't work. Official instructions found [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/ios/). My instructions: Open XCode and right-click on the `Runner` in the top left then click `Add Files to "Runner"...` and upload your `GoogleService-Info`.
3. Update any `firebase_SOMETHING` dependencies from your `pubspec.yaml` to their newest versions. For example, I had `firebase_analytics` in my `pubspec.yaml` that looked like this: `firebase_analytics: ^10.4.4` and I changed it to `firebase_analytics: ^10.5.1`. You can check the newest versions of a package on [pub](https://pub.dev).
4. From your project directory (the one containing `lib`, `ios`, etc.) you want to run: `cd ios ; pod repo update ; rm Podfile.lock ; pod install --repo-update ; cd .. ; flutter clean ; flutter pub get ; flutter run`.

After this, my app ran for the first time in days :)

Answer (score 0):

I working this with Flutter Cocoapods v1.13.0

brew command

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

without brew

```
sudo gem upgrade cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of flutter_inappwebview.
ie. flutter_inappwebview: ^5.8.0.
They have fixed the issue in the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I fixed all my Xcode 15 issues with flutter by going into [System Settings -> General -> Storage -> Developer -> & Delete the XCode Cache]