# Xcode 15: Undefined symbols: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode

upon upgrading to Xcode 15, my widget extension is causing this error:
`Undefined symbols:  Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

When pressing the error, nothing happens. It doesn't show me which symbols are undefined.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Go to the Report Navigator and open the full build log. You should see a more detailed error description of the linker error, it may give a hint of the root cause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try adding -ld_classic to the linker options

from

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731089

this worked in my case, It forces use of the old linker, the new linker is used by default in Xcode 15.

Addition info here..

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715385

Comment: Must admit, I deleted & recreated my IOS folder using 'flutter create --platforms ios .' simply because I was rushing to update my app because IOS 17 broke something major in it, but I hope your solution helps others!

Answer (score 1):

Open your project -> targets -> and add "-ld64" to "Other linker Flags

Comment: -Id64 is no longer used according to XCode warning, -Id_classic is the updated use case

Answer (score 0):

Updating Firebase from 10.2 to 10.16 resolved the issue for me. The previously used BoringSSL-GRPC dependency, which caused the error for me, is now also gone.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if someone else has this problem and it's not solved by the checked answer, is that you have two or more Targets defined, and have accidentally only added a dependent library/package to one of them, and are trying to build another one. The library will be in your list when you look at the project files, and it will appear in the Project's Package Dependencies, but it will fail with this error on linking the alternate Target.

To determine if this is the case, instead of looking at the project's Package Dependencies, instead look at the Target's Build Phases under "Link Binary With Libraries". You should see your package dependencies there. If they're not, click the plus (+) and add them.