# xcode 15, c++ compilation errors

Tags: xcode, gcc, compiler-errors, macports, xcode-command-line-tools

I just installed xcode 15 (because git wouldn't work without doing so). I didn't note what version I had before.

Now I can't compile some c++ code, which was compiling perfectly well before. when I try to `make`, the following output is shown:

```
g++-mp-12 -std=c++14 -Wall -O3 -fopenmp -o owt1d-nonlocal main.o linear.o nonlinear.o read.o energy.o intensity.o spectrum.o initialise.o flux.o fourier.o  -L/opt/local/lib -framework Accelerate -march=native -lfftw3 -lfftw3_threads -lopenblas -larmadillo -lm -lpthread
-macosx_version_min has been renamed to -macos_version_min
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lgcc'
0  0x100a97648  __assert_rtn + 72
1  0x1009cbfac  ld::AtomPlacement::findAtom(unsigned char, unsigned long long, ld::AtomPlacement::AtomLoc const*&, long long&) const + 1204
2  0x1009e1924  ld::InputFiles::SliceParser::parseObjectFile(mach_o::Header const*) const + 15164
3  0x1009eee30  ld::InputFiles::parseAllFiles(void (ld::AtomFile const*) block_pointer)::$_7::operator()(unsigned long, ld::FileInfo const&) const + 420
4  0x193098440  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
5  0x1930abf1c  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 224
6  0x193098400  _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7  0x1930a9fb8  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 684
8  0x1930aa6c0  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
9  0x193244038  _pthread_wqthread + 228
ld: Assertion failed: (resultIndex < sectData.atoms.size()), function findAtom, file Relocations.cpp, line 1336.
ld: warning: duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('/opt/local/lib/libgcc')
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [owt1d-nonlocal] Error 1
```

I installed c++ and all the libraries used for this code with MacPorts, and I have tried updating all my installed ports, but the same error is produced.

I'm really not sure about going into the guts of the installations, and don't know where to start resolving the duplicate paths. Is there an easy fix? Or will I have to try downgrading my version of xcode (not ideal)?

Comment: Hi, I had the same issue with git/xcode update... Have you tried checking you're using the compiler from MacPorts with ```which g++-mp-12```?

Comment: yes, it's in ```/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-12``` so definitely the one I installed with MacPorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. Xcode15 was automatically installed and since then I can no longer link my code with gcc. The only solution that worked was to reinstall Xcode 14.3.1 from the Apple developer site.

Comment: Thanks. I might have to try that. There are other forum posts about other stuff breaking when users install Xcode 15, remove it, and reinstall 14. When you reinstalled 14 did everything still work for you? And what exact instructions did you follow to do the reinstall? (I don't want to break things any more than they are already!) Cheers.

Comment: After reinstalling Xcode14.3.1 everything worked fine for me. I did not remove Xcode15 explicitly, but just overwrote it with Xcode14.3.1. The way I did it was to download Xcode_14.3.1.xip from the Apple developer website, see https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_14.3.1/Xcode_14.3.1.xip. Than I unpacked this file which generates one Xcode file containing the complete the Xcode14.3.1 package. Then I just copied the package to my application folder, overwriting Xcode15 as such. When you copy Xcode14.3.1 to the application folder, make sure that Xcode is not running.

Comment: Xcode 14.3.1 does not seem to be allowed to run under macOS Sonoma 14.0!

Answer (score 2):

(for future reference):

Jacques Bloch's solution - revert back to Xcode 14.3.1 - definitely sorts out the problem.

An alternative is to use the linker flag `-ld_classic` on compilation (see [Xcode 15: Undefined symbols: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77139621/xcode-15-undefined-symbols-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-s)).

Let's hope they fix xcode 15 sometime soon!

Comment: Did you somehow manage to revert to Xcode 14.3.1 under macOS Sonoma? I tried, but then Xcode 14.3.1 gave error message that it could not run under this OS!

Comment: You sadly cannot use Xcode 14.3.1 on Sonoma. I reverted my Mac to Ventura so I could use Xcode 14.

Comment: I haven't "up"graded to Sonoma yet. I definitely won't now that I know you can't use Xcode 14 on it!