# Flutter DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I am getting this error in flutter ios!!
Firebase:
DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

I tried every solution flutter clean , pub get
but did not help me!!
Please suggest me proper solution!!

Comment: I guess you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136958/flutter-or-react-native-xcode-15-error-xcode-dt-toolchain-dir-cannot-be-used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This help me to resolve the issue
[Flutter or React Native Xcode 15 Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136958/flutter-or-react-native-xcode-15-error-xcode-dt-toolchain-dir-cannot-be-used)

`flutter clean` -> `pod deintagrate` -> `flutter pub get`

Then I add in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

Run a `pod update`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it's worked for me

Whenever you update the XCode, you need to update Cocoapods

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

clean the the installed packages using the command “`flutter clean`” and install again saving pubspec.yaml file. then on the project folder redirect to the ios folder and install pods again

```
pod install
```

That's it.

My Xcode version:
Version 15.0.1 (15A507)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run a project where the pods were set up using Xcode 14.3 in Xcode 15.0, I faced the `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` error. I solved it by doing the following:

- First, removed the pods from the project by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/5990547)
- Cleared the `DerievedData` directory
- Added the below script at the end of the `podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

- Then ran `pod install`

This fixed my problem.

Similarly, in order to run the project where the pods are set up using Xcode 15.0 in Xcode 14.3, I used the below approach:

- First, removed the pods from the project by following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427883/5990547)
- Cleared the `DerievedData` directory
- Run `sudo gem update xcodeproj`
- Then ran `pod install`.

You can also use `pod cache clean --all` before `pod install`