# DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead in xcode 15

Tags: xcode15, macos-sonoma

I am trying to build a native iOS project after upgrading to the latest Xcode 15 and [macOS v14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sonoma) (Sonoma). Earlier it was working fine in Xcode 14.

While Building the project, I am getting these errors:

1. Firebase - DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead
2. FirebaseAnalytics - DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead
3. GoogleMLKit - DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

How can I fix it?

I tried a few options on my own and will list those below.

1. update the build settings in your Xcode project to use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead of DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR.

   - Open Your Xcode Project: 
     Open your Xcode project that is experiencing the build errors.
   - Navigate to Build Settings: 
     Navigate to the project or target's Build Settings.
   - Find LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS: 
     Locate the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS build setting.
   - Update DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR: 
     If you find any references to DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR, update them to use TOOLCHAIN_DIR.
   - Replace DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with TOOLCHAIN_DIR: 
     Replace DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with TOOLCHAIN_DIR in the build settings.
   - Save and Rebuild: 
     Save your changes and attempt to rebuild your project.
2. POD Update
3. *Clean Build* and rebuild

Comment: This issue has been fixed in CocoaPods version 1.13.0, as reported by Piero Ramos in his answer below.

Answer (score 184):

This error occurs after updating Xcode to 15 because of some CocoaPods version, so updating it and flushing the caches should solve this problem.

Follow the steps below:

1. Go to the `ios/` folder

   ```
   cd ios
   ```
2. Update CocoaPods

   ```
   sudo gem update cocoapods
   ```
3. If the above doesn't work, try installing it through [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))

   ```
   brew install cocoapods
   ```
4. Make sure CocoaPods updated to 1.13.0 or newer version (if available)

   ```
   pod --version
   ```
5. Delete the build cache

   ```
   flutter clean
   ```
6. Delete the *Podfile.lock* file

   ```
   rm Podfile.lock
   ```
7. Delete the *Pods/* folder as well

   ```
   rm -rf Pods/
   ```
8. Install the Flutter package dependencies

   ```
   flutter pub get
   ```
9. Install the iOS pod dependencies

   ```
   pod install
   ```
10. Update your local pods

    ```
    pod update
    ```

Comment: what does flutter and AndroidStudio have to do with an Xcode problem?^^

Comment: This issue has been fixed in CocoaPods version 1.13.0, as reported by Piero Ramos in his answer below.

Comment: solved my issue for capacitor, just ignored flutter stuff

Comment: for Cordova: swapped `flutter clean` for `cordova clean` and swapped `flutter pub get` for `cordova prepare` and skipped the part about Android Studio.

Comment: been struggling for weeks, finally fixed!

Comment: `pod install` is not needed, if you do `pod update`

Comment: Excellently explained step-to-step guide, even though these steps take a huge amount of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: `sudo gem update cocoapods` took like 20 min so be patient...

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly working.

Answer (score 83):

In Xcode 15, Apple made a modification to the variable that points to the default toolchain location, replacing $DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR with $TOOLCHAIN_DIR. If your project or target relies on the previous variable, you should update it to use $TOOLCHAIN_DIR.

To perform this replacement, you can add the following code snippet at the end of your project's Podfile:

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

After making this change in your Podfile, you will need to install the pods again via the terminal using the command:

```
pod install
```

### For Flutter developers

To enhance your script's functionality, kindly insert the following line:

> flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

Here is the modified script with this addition:

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: None of the solution worked for me. :(

Comment: "For Flutter Developers" worked for me.
Both IntelliJ (Flutter) and Xcode build successfully done!

Comment: MY iOS doesn't have such feild, it didn't work at all

Comment: For Flutter solution worked flawlessly. Use find "flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)" and replace it with the code below.

Comment: This worked for me with flutter too

Answer (score 17):

Go to pods → *Firebase* → *Support files*, both *.release* and *.debug* files.

Change "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR" into "TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead".
It works for me.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me! However, I'm not pretty sure why... Is this because a specific Firebase pod configuration?

I'm developing for iOS 17.2, Xcode 15.2, Flutter 3.16

Answer (score 17):

For newbie IOS developer like me.

Go to `Find` -> `Find and Replace in workspace`

[image]

Press `Replace ALL` and then

IMPORTANT: Do not forget to save using `CMD + S`

Then clean the build.

`Product` -> `Clean Build Folder` and click run

Comment: This is great! I guess we should sometimes read the error message text before googling it. lol

Answer (score 8):

It was solved after changing the podfile.

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
      xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
      xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
      File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a good practice to include explanations in your solution to help others understand what's happening under the hood.

Comment: You just copied already posted answer.

Comment: Other answers has been edited. @vrnvorona

Answer (score 8):

***Updated 11 October 2023 Solutions*** If you faced this issue after updating to Xcode 15 and can't run your Flutter app on iOS platform.

**Solution 1: Update CocoaPods to v1.13 ([1.13 released a fix](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065#issuecomment-1732182840))**

It seems to be an issue due to old CocoaPods version with Xcode 15. This is resolved in the CocoaPods version 1.13.0.

You can follow the steps above *[DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead in xcode 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77219650/dt-toolchain-dir-cannot-be-used-to-evaluate-library-search-paths-use-toolchain/77229768#77229768)*.

**Solution 2: Update Podfile (Flutter / Xcode 15)**

However, it's important to note that this should only be used as a temporary solution until a CocoaPods update comes out that fixes your Xcode version.

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
  end
end
```

For non-Flutter users: Remove the below line from the script.

```
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
```

**Additional fixes related: Update Flutter libraries**

If you use inAppWebview, an error like this will appear:

> Parse Issue (Xcode): Could not build module 'WebKit'

Update inAppWebview to [v5.8.0 release](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/releases/tag/v5.8.0):

```
flutter_inappwebview: 5.8.0
```

Look for updates on the libraries you are using within your Flutter project.

***Remember*** **after using any of the above solutions**

1. Clean your Flutter project: `flutter clean` && `flutter pub get`
2. Remove Pods directory inside the iOS directory: `rm Podfile.lock` && `rm -rf Pods/`
3. Install and update pods: `pod install` && `pod update`
4. Build and test your app on an iOS device: `flutter run`. Or build within your Xcode.

Note: "pod update" will update the pod to the latest version possible (as long as it matches the version restrictions in your Podfile), so it is safe to use on Flutter.

Comment: I don't think you actually need pod update for such operations, since it's Flutter that manages versions of dependencies.

Comment: To clarify "pod update" is safe to run on flutter, pod will update to the latest possible version according to podfile. Added a note to my post.

Answer (score 6):

When I tried to run a project whose pod is set up using Xcode 14.3 in Xcode 15.0, I faced the DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR error. I solved it by the following:

- I first removed the CocoaPods from the project and followed *[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/16427883#16427883)*:
- Cleared the `DerievedData`
- I have written the below script at the end of `podfile`:

  ```ruby
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
        xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
        File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- then used `pod install`.

This fixed my problem.

Similarly, in order to run the project whose pod is set up using Xcode 15.0 in Xcode 14.3, I used the below approach:

- First removed CocoaPods from the project. I followed
  *[How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project/16427883#16427883)*
- Cleared the `DerievedData`
- and ran `sudo gem update xcodeproj`
- then used `pod install`.

Note: You can use `pod cache clean --all` before `pod install`

Comment: Outstanding ....

Comment: Even though I'm running XCode 15.2, the second part only did the trick for me. I didn't need to change my podfile. I always try first the easiest way to fix something, so "sudo gem update xcodeproj" + "pod cache clean --all" (that was very important) + "pod install" solved my problem. Thank you for the clue!

Answer (score 3):

For me work update cocoapods, which fix problem with xCode 15.

Upgrade Cocoapods v1.13.0.

Brew command:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Without Brew:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then run in your project/ios folder

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Note:
If you can just migrate to package manager. Especially when you starting new project.

Answer (score 2):

I followed these steps:

1. Open terminal and run this command: sudo gem install cocoapods
2. After installation, navigate to project folder and run this command: pod update

Answer (score 2):

Cocoapads needs to be updated for Xcode 15 to work.
Go to terminal => your project => cd ios => **sudo gem install cocoapods**

Now go to Xcode -> Runner -> build Settings -> Check DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR is replaced with TOOLCHAIN_DIR.If it is replaced, then it will work

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? (It seems to me to be repeating the core guidance from previous answers.) **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines to your Podfile and it will fix the issue. It renames all `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` to `TOOLCHAIN_DIR` after pods are installed.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
      xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
      IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.base_configuration_reference.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXFileReference
        xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
        IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For non-[Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)), or I should say for people code use native Swift in their projects. Adding the following snippet in my Podfile fixed it for me.

```ruby
post_install do |installer|
    xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # For xcode 15+ only
            if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I understand this is a temporary solution. The people who owns these pods are responsible for fixing this permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to and open with sudo with [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano), `sudo nano`. Paste the path:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebsiteDataStore.h
```

Search for: `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED`.
Change it from `170000` to `180000`.

Navigate to your pod file. Comment as commented below:

```ruby
  # installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
  #   project.targets.each do |target|
  #     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  #         config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
  #       end
  #   end
  # end
```

Then add this:

```ruby
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if Gem::Version.new(config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET']) < Gem::Version.new('13.0')
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
      end
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
    xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
    xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
    File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of Xcode 15.

I reverted back to Xcode 14.2 or 14.3 by removing the 15 version and downloading the 14.2 xip file, and moved extracted Xcode to "Applications", without opening Xcode and creating Simulator with iOS <16... It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to CocoaPods. Please refer to [this comment](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12065#issuecomment-1733932330) on the CocoaPods GitHub issue for the fix. It worked for me and many others who were mainly running *native* iOS projects, but some were also running *hybrid* projects.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change All Pods iOS Deployment Target ios Version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).