# How do I use firebase sdk in xcode15?

Tags: firebase, sdk, xcode15

error : DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avE04.jpg)
The same error keeps happening.

I even put RunScript down to the bottom.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lniM.png)

I'm developing it as a flutter. Please let me know if anyone has solved the same problem.

Comment: If the error is associated with a code, do not use images. You must copy the code in text format to be able to verify it and facilitate its manipulation.

Comment: and according to what I investigated, the problem is solved with the post installation of hook in cocoapods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12012

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 That podfile hook is intermittent at best. Tried for hours to get it working but no go. However, see Mecki answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76791937/issues-while-building-ios-project-with-flutter/77128055#77128055) as it has been very reliable across different SDK's with the same issue. It's the answer using the terminal to paste a command starting with `find . -name...`.

Comment: I am marking this question as a duplicate as *lots* of SDK's are not working due to the same issue and the linked question (and answers) provide a variety of solutions.